# Displaying content corrsponding to clicked TreeView Item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I'm not sure how to display content in a Panel when the user clicks an item in the TreeView when there are multiple levels of items.

[image]

I've seen this everywhere, but not sure where to start. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.Node.Text)
    {
        case "General":
        // Do something...
        break;

        // Etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I typically use the tree's AfterSelect event handler such as:

```
private void tree_Detail_AfterSelect(Object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
swich (tree_Detail.SelectedNode.Name)
{
    case "node1":
        //display node 1 content in panel
        break;
    case "node2":
        //display node 2 content in panel
        break;
    //...etc...
    }
}
```

You could also use each tree node's Tag property (an Object) to store something such as an identifying Integer value and react to that instead of the text name.  But I will usually just name the nodes prefixed with "node" so that I can react to them in a recognizable way in code.

Comment: Thanks @Don, I will accept when the timer runs out. I already figured it out by the time I saw your answer but I'll accept yours since it works anyway.